# The decay of $\chi_c$ into $l \bar l$?

Tags: particle-physics, leptons

I know that the states  $\chi_c$ cannot decay into $l\bar l$ and therefore cannot be made in a lepton-anti lepton collider. I can see why such a decay is not allowed via a virtual photon. Since (please correct me if I am wrong) parity is conserved *at vertices* in EM interaction since the parity of the $\chi _c$ is $+$ and the parity of a photon is $-$ such a decay would violate parity conservation. However, I cannot see why a decay through a $Z_0$ boson is forbidden, since in such a decay we do not need to conserve parity. So why is such a decay forbidden?

Comment: Weak *production*? Have you considered the cross section? The $f_0(500)$ is likewise $0^{++}$; why don't you get that one?

Comment: How did you decide (insignificant, low rate) weak decays are forbidden? But this is a monster, 11 MeV wide...